# Automate Page creation with Sections in Symphony CMS

Tags: symphony-cms

I am using the latest version of the Symphony CMS.  I have a section for "projects"  but I would like each project to have its own unique url.  For example, I want to fill out all of the information, title, description, technical specs for the project then provide a url name.  Hopefully, when I click create, a new page will then be created containing all of the information.  I'm not sure that this is even possible but would really like to know.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed very possible, but you don't need to have a Symphony "page" for each project.

Instead, you create a Projects page with, for example, a `project` [URL parameter](http://www.getsymphony.com/learn/concepts/view/url-parameters/). You then create a [data source](http://www.getsymphony.com/learn/concepts/view/data-sources/) that is [filtered](http://www.getsymphony.com/learn/concepts/view/data-source-filters/) by this page's URL parameter on the name field, which will give you `/projects/name-of-project-one` and `/projects/name-of-project-two`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was able to do just as you suggested and it works like a charm.  Thank you!